# Which language correction sites have a large number of active Mongolian speakers?

Tags: mongolian, language-exchange, language-correction

I've been (kind of) learning Mongolian for over a year, and I've been actively correcting native speakers of Mongolian on lang-8 during that time. There aren't a lot of Mongolian users, and many of those users post only one or two entries before giving up, or only post occasionally. By contrast, there are lots of native speakers of Japanese, and many of them are active on the website frequently and for a long time.

My problem could just be that there's not many native speakers of Mongolian, but I don't know. Is my problem that native speakers of Mongolian are more likely to use different language correction sites, and if so, which sites do they use?

Answer (score 4):

The main issue may be ... Internet access in Mongolia: according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_in_Mongolia#Internet) (emphasis added),

> The Internet, established in 1995 in Mongolia, has yet to make a significant impact, with **only 16% of the population having access to it as of 2012**.

[Melinda Soós](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2010/may/20/mongolia), who was teaching English in Mongolia in 2010, wrote in *The Guardian* that the biggest challenge there was (emphasis added):

> Access to English language resources: I have a whiteboard and imagination. Even if the availability of English resources, **including teachers and the internet**, improved, could professionals who missed out on learning English in school afford access?

So, another factor is how many Mongolians know English. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia#Languages), Russian is (or was?) the most important foreign language. However, according to an [article on the Mongolia Focus blog](https://blogs.ubc.ca/mongolia/2016/foreign-languages-mongolians/) (May 2016), English may have overtaken Russian as the most important/popular foreign language in Mongolia. However, the informal survey that provided the data for this statement was run on Facebook and Twitter, which may have a higher percentage of English-speaking Mongolians than the population at large.

The rising importance of English in Mongolia is the consequence of a politic decision just over a decade ago. See e.g. [The new second language of Mongolia is... English](http://www.bookofjoe.com/2005/02/the_new_second_.html) (book of joe, February 2005) and [English in Mongolia](http://languagehat.com/english-in-mongolia/) (LanguageHat, February 2005).

What I have written so far only shows that English is on the rise in Mongolia and that Internet access cannot be taken for granted. So where on the Internet do you find native speakers of Mongolian who know English?

italki currently has only [one tutor for Mongolian](https://www.italki.com/teachers/mongolian), compared to 8 for Slovak, which has roughly the same number of native speakers. (According to Wikipedia, both Mongolian and Slovak have 5.2 million native speakers, but the census data are not from the same years.)

I don't see Mongolian on [Busuu](https://www.busuu.com/en/), [LingQ](http://www.lingq.com/).

- [Lang-8 has a few groups for Mongolian](http://lang-8.com/groups?keywords=mongolian), but you knew that already...
- [How to Learn Mongolian via Online Language Exchange](https://www.mylanguageexchange.com/Learn/Type_Ex.asp?HU=Mongolian.asp) also has a list of Mongolian-speaking members.
- Tribalingual is a site dedicated to rare and endangered languages; they also offer a [10-week Mongolian course](http://tribalingual.com/course/mongolian/).
- Tatoeba has [a few hundred sentences in Mongolian](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show_all_in/mon/none/none).

I'll update my answer when I find more sites.